# Keycloak is not using the userinfo endpoint to get the user info from idp

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I'm encountering an issue with Keycloak while integrating with an external Identity Provider (IdP). The IdP is sending an encoded ID token. Instead of decoding the ID token, I would like Keycloak to utilize the UserInfo endpoint for obtaining user information.

## Details:

Keycloak Version: 8.0.2 (old OS, can't upgraded keycloak until a more recente OS installation)

External IdP Type: OIDC

Description of the Problem: Keycloak is trying to decode the id_token instead of using the userinfo endpoint, how the id_token is encoded, keycloak raise an error:

> ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-54) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: Invalid token

This error is after using the /token endpoint

## What I've Tried:

Have changed mappers, on client on idp, and cleared cache

## Question:

I'm looking for guidance on configuring Keycloak to use the UserInfo endpoint when the external IdP is sending an encoded ID token that Keycloak cannot decode. Has anyone encountered a similar scenario or have insights on how to configure Keycloak to rely on the UserInfo endpoint in such cases?